# JSON parsed object and wild card

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function that is supposed to check old data against data. I am parsing data and oldData to get a JSON object respectively as dbData and formData are simply strings containing ID's and values for the HTMML form. The purpuse of the function is to check if the user has made any textchanges some textareas in the HTML form. I want to do this by checking the ID for each textarea and then check if the value in formData and Data are the same. In that case no change has been made and the function will return true.

The data string im parsing looks something like this:

```
"[{\"texts\":[{\"default\":true,\"bread-texts\":false,\"textarea1\":\"Banana\",\"textarea2\":\"Kiwi\",\"textarea3\":\Apple \",\"textarea4\":\"coffe\",\"textarea5\":\"Tea\",\"signature\":true,\"profile\":\"header\",\"fontsize\":\"26\",\"fontsize-headers\":\"10.5\",\"fontcolor\":\"#0000\",\"textfont\":\"header-large\",\"textsub1\":\"Bold\",\"font\":\"ICA%20Text\",\"textsub\":\"Regular\",\"textsize\":\"20\",\"textsize-signature\":\"9.5\",\"textsizesmall\":\"5.5\",\"textsizesmall-placer\":\"2.75\",\"vers-placer\":\"false\",\"text-colored\":\"%23000000\",\"s-all-customers\":true,\"new-customers\":true,\"undefined\":\"\"}]}]"
```

So for example, i have to check the ID for "textarea1"  in dbData and formData and then check if the value is the same. Can this be done using wildcard or is there a better way to archive this?

```
function CheckValues() {

    var isChanged = false;
    var formData = $.parseJSON(data);
    var dbData = $.parseJSON(oldData);                  
    if(formData !== dbData) {
        var isChanged = true;
    }   
    return isChanged;
}
```

Comment: Your JSON string has syntax error... - in this `\"textarea3\":\"Milk" \"`... So this `$.parseJSON` will return `false`, because your object structure is wrong...

Comment: There is no easy why to compare two objects. If the data structure of old and new json string are the same you could just compare the JSON strings with `if(data === oldData){` rather than parse them both.

Comment: Th real json string im using works fine. I had to take it out of context just for demonstration. I cant compare data with old Data as the strings contains id's for other objects than the textareas. I have to check the textareas only not the entire form.

Comment: updated the text containing the object structure

Answer (score 1):

```
The code shown below works in IE9+, Chrome, FireFox but other
browsers yet to test. The example shows two different values, data and 
OldData - data contains "Tea" where as OldData contains "OldTea" so 
isChanged flag is true.
function CheckValues() {
            var data = "{\"disable\":false,\"textarea1 
            \":\"Banana\",\"textarea2\":\"Kiwi\",\"textarea3 
            \":\"Milk\",\"textarea4\":\"Coffe\",\"textarea5\":\"Tea\"}";

            var oldData = "{\"disable\":false,\"textarea1 
            \":\"Banana\",\"textarea2\":\"Kiwi\",\"textarea3 
            \":\"Milk\",\"textarea4\":\"Coffe\",\"textarea5\":\"OldTea\"}";

            var formData = JSON.parse(data);
            var dbData = JSON.parse(oldData);

            var oFormData = Object.keys(formData);
            var oDbData = Object.keys(dbData);

            var isChanged = false;
            if (oFormData.length === oDbData.length)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < oFormData.length; i++) {
                    var propName = oFormData[i];
                    if (typeof (dbData[propName]) === "undefined") {
                        isChanged = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (formData[propName] !== dbData[propName]) {
                            isChanged = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Very interesting and informative. I have to look up object.keys. I want to avoid working with fixed values though because the user might make a change in a textarea so the value may change. Instead i have to check if propName is "textarea1", "textarea2" and so on.